# Enable query string access only to select few Controller functions?

Tags: codeigniter

In few pages I need to make pagination. This of course can be achieved with URI segments, but in few cases in addition to pagination parameters, I need to pass some other GET parameters for filtering purposes.

So obviously in this case i need to be able access the controller via query string like so:

```
example.com/?c=controller&m=function
```

In order to achieve this I set the `enable_query_strings` to TRUE in main config file.

This seemed to work, but I discovered that it breaks a bunch of different stuff. For example if I use `current_url()` the URL returned has a `?` at the end to accommodate the query string. So if I use it in form, it does not work.

So is there any way to enable the controller access to controller functions only to specified functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct you url like this:

```
/param1/param2/pagination_parameters
```

So you will be able to send custom data (number of params), and pagination data using just URI segments.

> For example if I use current_url() the URL returned has a ? at the end
>   to accommodate the query string. So if I use it in form, it does not
>   work.

Please note, that you can also left form 'action' blank, so result will be the same as if you had used current_url() (http request will go to the same script).

Comment: That is not really an option. There is variable amount of parameters (in some cases no parameters at all), so the only feasible way is to have a key=value pairs.

And leaving blank does indeed work for this problem! Thanks. Still though would like to find solution where I can specify what controller functions can be accessed via query string and which cannot

Comment: "So is there any way to enable the controller access to controller  functions only to specified functions?"

Please could you explain why do you want to do it, what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Well there is in a couple of pages pagination, which has to work with variable amount of get parameters. So I want to make it possible to access these pages via query string. And if I enable global query string access, it f*cks up other thingz.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enabling enable_query_strings in main config, just enable in pagination config only. So it will apply to that particular page only.

Ex:

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: This option only affects the formatting of the link, it does not make the actual function accessible via query string.